# overriding issue of previous selection of dropdown component in the parent component

Tags: angular

I have a pair of currency and country dropdowns each in my angular application. There is drop down component that is referenced in the parent component. So in my form there is this country component that is displayed on the left as well as right side. Same is the case  for currency component. The needed behaviour is when the user selects the country component on the left, the country component on the right should be disable and reflect the same value as that of the selected component on the left. Same is the case for currency component.

I have defined a subject in the service. I emit value to the subject in the dropdown component. The subscription to the subject happens in the parent component. Now since both the dropdown controls are dependent on the same subject, selecting one dropdown overrides the other. What do I do tackle this scenario .

I am using `[showAlternateDropDown]="accounts.controls[i].get('yesNoMultilingual')?.value` and `[alternateDropDownCode]="countrySelected` input properties to tell the common dropdown control what to display.

So basically when I select country in the one dropdown , the other country dropdown shows correctly however the moment I select currency, the country dropdown previously select gets overriden and looses its binding as the the value is currency code and not countrycode.

parent component markup:

```
<div class="field">
   <label for="bankAddressCountry" translate>
   common.address.country
   </label>
   <app-ref-select [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" formControlName="bankAddressCountry"
      name="bankAddressCountry" id="bankAddressCountry" ref="countries" enableTranslation="true">
   </app-ref-select>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <label for="alternateBankAddressCountry" translate>
   common.address.country
   </label>
   <app-ref-select [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" formControlName="alternateBankAddressCountry" 
   [showAlternateDropDown]="accounts.controls[i].get('yesNoMultilingual')?.value" 
   [alternateDropDownCode]="countrySelected"
   name="alternateBankAddressCountry" id="alternateBankAddressCountry" ref="countries" enableTranslation="true">
   </app-ref-select>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <label for="bankCurrency" translate>
   common.currency
   </label>
   <app-ref-select [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" formControlName="bankCurrency"
      name="bankCurrency" id="bankCurrency" ref="currencies" enableTranslation="true"></app-ref-select>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <label for="alternateBankCurrency" translate>
   common.currency
   </label>
   <app-ref-select [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" formControlName="alternateBankCurrency"  [showAlternateDropDown]="accounts.controls[i].get('yesNoMultilingual')?.value" 
   [alternateDropDownCode]="countrySelected"
   name="alternateBankCurrency" id="alternateBankCurrency" ref="currencies" enableTranslation="true">
   </app-ref-select>
</div>
```

Parent component file:

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private kycService: KycService) {
    super();
    this.id = 'BANK_DETAILS';
    this.kycService.countrySeletion$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.countrySelected = res;  });
  }
```

KycService

```
countrySeletion$ = new Subject();
```

Dropdown component:

```
export class SelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ref: string;
  @Input() options: NameCode[] = [];
  @Input() hideDefaultOption = false;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() showAlternateDropDown: boolean;
  @Input() alternateDropDownCode?;
  @Input() enableTranslation: boolean; 

  constructor(private referenceStore: ReferenceStore, private kycService: KycService) {
  }

  select(option: string) {
    if (!this.disabled) {
      this.value = option;
      this.kycService.countrySeletion$.next(this.value);
      this.onChanged(option);
      this.onTouched();
    }
```

Dropdown component markup:

```
<select *ngIf="!showAlternateDropDown; else test" (change)="select($event.target.value)" [disabled]="disabled">
  <option *ngIf="!hideDefaultOption" value="" translate>common.please-select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.code" [selected]="value ===  opt.code">
    {{ enableTranslation ? (ref + '.' + opt.code | translate) : opt.name }}
  </option>
</select>

<ng-template #test>
  <select [disabled]="true">
    <option  [value]="alternateDropDownCode">
      {{ enableTranslation && alternateDropDownCode ? (ref + '.' + alternateDropDownCode | translate) : ''}}
    </option>
  </select>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: "selecting one dropdown overrides the other", I'm unclear if this is what you want or this is unintended and something you want to stop?

Comment: I want to stop. So I should be able to use currency and countries dropdown in this instance without affecting one or the other.

Comment: How about adding another input property on the drop down component.  Pass CU for currency drop downs , CO for country drop downs.  While emitting the value in drop down component , emit it with property prefixing . While subscribing , initialise variables based on prefix. So if the variable is countryselected, initialise it with country code if the observable value has a prefix of CO . Is that a good way of handling it.

Comment: This way we can initialise multiple variables on the form like , countrySelected, currencySelected etc